# AWS Athena $path equivalent in GlueContext create_dynamic_frame_from_options()

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-athena

So in AWS Athena we can use `"$path"` in select query and we get s3 path where that data is stored.
ex: `my_s3_bucket/dev/dev-data=[date]/[something random alphanumeric]`

date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`

so how can I get the same path but using `GlueContext`'s `create_dynamic_frame_from_options()` method/function
where `connection_type` will be `S3` and `connection_options` will have s3 paths.
ex: `my_s3_bucket/data/dev-data=2022-10-16/`

I would like to see the complete path by using DynamicFrame which will be `my_s3_bucket/dev/dev-data=2022-10-16/[something random alphanumeric]`

how to do that?